# Migrating master user to service principal for authentication on power bi embedded

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, service-principal

I'm trying to migrating my authentication method from Power BI Master User to service principal.

on master user I'm using msal with authentication flow like bellow:
login to AAD --> request for AAD token --> importing pbix file with rest API using AAD token as credential

this is the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    myMSALObj.loginPopup(requestObj).then(function (loginResponse) {
        acquireTokenPopup();
    });
    Msal.UserAgentApplication
});

function acquireTokenPopup() {
    myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(requestObj).then(function (tokenResponse) {
        AADToken = tokenResponse.accessToken;
        importPBIX(AADToken);
    });
}

function importPBIX(accessToken) {
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "./importPBIX?accessToken=" + accessToken + "&pbixTemplate=" + pbixTemplate, true);
    //the rest of import process//
}
```

so there are two question:
1. what kind of flow would it be if I use service principal instead?
   on my head and from the info which I read from microsoft document it would be simpler like:
   request token using application secret key -->  importing pbix file with rest API using token
   is this correct?
2. what kind of code that I can use to do this on javascript?I think MSAL couldn't do token request by using service principal. would appreciate any info or tutorial for this.

bests,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to Jim's answer, I've tweaked my code a little bit and the token authentication process went smoothly.
As my apps using javascript at front-end and python as its back-end, I decided to do the process at python and used python msal library instead.
the code is just like :

```
authority_host_uri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com'
tenant = 'myTenantId'
authority_uri = authority_host_uri + '/' + tenant
client_id = 'myClienId'
client_secret = 'myClientSecretKey'
config={"scope":["https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default"]}

app = ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, client_credential=client_secret, authority=authority_uri)
token = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=config['scope'])
```

once again thanks to Jim for helping me on this one.

bests,

Comment: What are prerequisites for the service principal to access Power BI resources? I used your code but the response is empty.

Comment: Hi , you must register your application with service principal token on app registrations in Azure.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. ***what kind of flow would it be if I use service principal instead? on my head and from the info which I read from microsoft document it would be simpler like: request token using application secret key --> importing pbix file with rest API using token is this correct?***

According to my research, if you want to use the service principal to get Azure AD access token, you can use the [client credentials grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)
[image]

1. The client application authenticates to the Azure AD token issuance endpoint and requests an access token.
2. The Azure AD token issuance endpoint issues the access token.
3. The access token is used to authenticate to the secured resource.
4. Data from the secured resource is returned to the client application.

Regarding how to get access token, please refer to the following steps

1. Register Azure AD application
   [image]
   [image]
2. Configure API permissions
   [image]
3. Get access token

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=<>
&client_secret=<>
&resource=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api
```

> ***2. what kind of code that I can use to do this on javascript?I think MSAL couldn't do token request by using service principal. would appreciate any info or tutorial for this.***

If you want to implement client credentials grant flow with sdk, you can use `adal-node`. For more details, please refer to https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-node.

For example

```
var AuthenticationContext = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;

var authorityHostUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/';
var tenant = 'myTenant.onmicrosoft.com'; // AAD Tenant name.
var authorityUrl = authorityHostUrl + '/' + tenant;
var applicationId = 'yourApplicationIdHere'; // Application Id of app registered under AAD.
var clientSecret = 'yourAADIssuedClientSecretHere'; // Secret generated for app. Read this environment variable.
var resource = ''; // URI that identifies the resource for which the token is valid.

var context = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);

context.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(resource, applicationId, clientSecret, function(err, tokenResponse) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('well that didn\'t work: ' + err.stack);
  } else {
    console.log(tokenResponse);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Jim, thank you for the explanation. now I have a better image for how the authentication go when using service principal.
for the code itself, right now I'm trying to use it. but every time I tried to use the "var AuthenticationContext = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;" code. it always return with  Module name "adal-node" has not been loaded yet for context: error, even if I already install adal-node using npm.

Comment: @oRoberto Since it is useful for you, could you please mark it?